# Using multiple USB hub on Q170 chipset

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-hub

I have an industrial type PC with a Q170 chipset and I want to connect more than 24 USB devices, such as printers, POS machines etc.

When we tried to connect all of them, some devices are not recognized by Windows and it is not a driver issue. When we decrease the load of USB devices (remove some of them) Windows can recognize the others.

The Intel page says:

> # of USB Ports: 14

But as I read, connecting up to 127 USB devices in single PC should work.
How many USB devices can I connect to this PC and what could be the reason of Windows not recognizing them?

Comment: It has 14 ports and the bus as whole per spec should support up to 127 (if I'm not mistaken) but that doesn't mean you can run all of them off a single port. If you're using hubs make sure that the hubs have a separate power channel. Depending on what those devices do they can't just keep pulling power from the port as the spec also limits that power depending on the version and type of USB port.

Comment: What kind of USB hubs did you try? Please tell the model and how did you power them. And how many exposed root ports does your "industrial PC" have?

Answer (score 0):

Examples of devices that are not recognized would be helpful in finding cause. Can you give some details?

Also, USB allows for connecting up to 127 devices, but there are limits:

1. Every hub is a device, limiting available pool. Your PC has at least several already, by the way.
2. You can do max 5 tiers (every hub is another tier, hub is a device to which you can connect another USB device in a daisychain)
3. USB has finite bandwidth, be sure you spread devices evenly across the hubs in your PC, some devices use way more than usual peripherals.
4. USB supplies finite power to each port, make sure you're using devices with own power or powered hubs as much as possible
5. Max cable length is different for each port standard (3.0 has max 5m, 2.0 max 3m)
6. It might be a good idea not to mix 3.0 and 2.0 devices on the same chain. Different speeds, available bandwidth and signal attenuation on the long cables all make difference.

If you took all that into account all that's left is to contact the PC manufacturer for assistance in your setup.